# ITMS-90035 Error After Changing Build System to "New Build System" in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

After I change build system from "Legacy Build System" to "New Build System" I started to get below error when trying to upload IPA to Appstore. For both options, I can get success build. What can be the problem?

**P.S:** My export options plist file is for Distrubition. Therefore, there is no problem with the certificate etc.. (As I mentioned, I can successfully UPLOAD it when build with legacy build system.

What I want to learn is that what can be the reasons for the problem. I'll check all of the reasons of it (e.g naming in files).

> ERROR ITMS-90035: "Invalid Signature. A sealed resource is missing or invalid. The file at path [Şans.app/Şans] is not properly signed. Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate. Verify that the code signing settings in Xcode are correct at the target level (which override any values at the project level). Additionally, make sure the bundle you are uploading was built using a Release target in Xcode, not a Simulator target. If you are certain your code signing settings are correct, choose "Clean All" in Xcode, delete the "build" directory in the Finder, and rebuild your release target. For more information, please consult https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: There are two types of `provision profiles` in iOS 1. Development 2. Production/Distribution. To publish apps on itunes you need Distribution certificate. Thats what error means.

Comment: Yes I know. As I mentioned the problem is between build systems not the certificate. I'm getting build with distribution certificate.

Answer (score 1):

There are may two possibilities in your case.

First: you are generating build using production/distribution certificate it's fine, but you must use `App Store` distribution provisioning profile instead of `Ad Hoc`.

[image]

Second thing you need to check, Is there any file exists with the special characters on it. For exemple: "IconFileName `(Cópia).png`" or `"Atalar sözləri oyunu.app"` etc. application archive does not support non-ASCII characters so rename file name if any exist.

Comment: I'll check your second recommendation

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue once. The real problem was that some assets were missing, in my case it was some AppIcon sizes. It don't known how it is "build system" related tbh.

Hope it helps